# printing mutableState parameters

Tags: kotlin, parameters, android-jetpack-compose, state, mutablestateof

I have a class Plan() that has the parameter "val changeNumber : MutableState<Double?>".
as in
Plan(
...
val changeNumber : MutableState<Double?>
...

){}

I want to display this value on the screen but when I use plan.changeNumber.toString() it displays "MutableState(value = 84.0)@1593929391

How do I just access the value if I can. or do I can I not even take it as a parameter if I want it to work?

I tried getValue (which is asking for another value inside but I cannot find the correct parameter to put in there) and toString. getValue gives an error and toString displays what I put above.

Comment: Sorry for the formatting, that is not what it looked like when I was reviewing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are displaying the instance of the MutableState.
You have to call `.value` to get the value:
`plan.changeNumber.value?.toString()`

Comment: Just missing that little bit. New to jetpack in case you couldn't tell lol. Thank you